# How can i get an Organisations Instances from Production?

Tags: salesforcedx

If i have lets say  a Production , SandBox and Developer Edition in Salesforce.
Is there a way I can login to one , probably Production and retrieve all instances registered to the Organisation. So logging into Production I can make some sort of ap[i call or apex call that will give me all instances assocaiated to this Organisation. (a link between Prod , Sandbox and Developer)

Thanks

Comment: There is no relationship between a developer edition org and a production org.

Comment: are you trying to get a list of scratch orgs associated with the DevHub (presumably PROD)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below REST call to get the list of Sandboxes created in the Production.

```
GET /services/data/v40.0/tooling/query/?q=Select+id,SandboxName+from+SandboxInfo
```

Also,please be informed that you can use the [SandboxInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sandboxinfo.htm) Object in Production only.